# Is it possible to select a range in a ListBox without raising the event multiple times?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

The question:

I have a ListBox in my form (the class is `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox`), in `MultiExtended` selection mode. Now I want to write a `Sub` that selects a range of items (e.g. all items) "in one go", i.e. as if the user selected them with a drag-selection.

The naive way is of course to select them one by one, using `SetSelected` etc. However, the problem is that I have a handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of this ListBox. Thus this handler will be called many times, slowing down the program.

So basically what I want is to do a range selection, and raising only one `SelectedIndexChanged` event. How can I do this?

---

What I have done and thought:

After searching, I find on MSDN that the class `System.Windows.Controls.ListBox` has a `SelectAll` method. Unfortunatedly (and strangely) there is no such kind of method for the class `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox`.

The roundabout idea I have now, is to detach the handler of `SelectedIndexChanged`, then select the items one by one, and finally re-attach the handler. But I still would like to know if there is a better way.

It is really strange if such a method is not provided, since the user can achieve this effect by a drag-selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two basic ways to do it.  As you mentioned, by removing the event handler:

```
RemoveHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
ListBox1.SetSelected(0, True)
ListBox1.SetSelected(2, True)
ListBox1.SetSelected(3, True)
AddHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ListBox1, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Technically, it's best to put that in a Try-Catch-Finally so if something goes wrong, the handler would always be re-attached in the finally section.

Or by using a boolean flag:

```
Private ignoreChange = False

Private Sub ChangeSomething()
  ignoreChange = True
  ListBox1.SetSelected(0, True)
  ListBox1.SetSelected(2, True)
  ListBox1.SetSelected(3, True)
  ignoreChange = False
  ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ListBox1, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  If Not ignoreChange Then
    '// do something...
  End If
End Sub
```